# Implementing concatenation by hand in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

How can I implement the concatenation operator in Haskell by hand? 
This is what I have so far, but I am struggling with the recursion at the end:

```
data MyList a = Empty | Element a (MyList a)
 deriving Show

concatenation:: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty Empty = Empty
concatenation a Empty = a
concatenation Empty a = a
concatenation x y = ???
```

Comment: Hint: pattern match with the `Element` constructor.

Comment: `concatenation (Element x xs) y = ?` (The first base case isn't necessary; `concatenation a Empty = a` works just fine if `a` matches `Empty`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using variables directly, we can enumerate over the constructors. There are thus four cases we need to cover:

```
concatenation:: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty Empty = -- ...
concatenation Empty (Element b bs) = -- ...
concatenation (Element a as) Empty = -- ...
concatenation (Element a as) (Element b bs) = -- ...
```

Now we can aim to solve those cases. Concatenating two `Empty` lists will return an empty list, so `Empty`.

```
concatenation Empty Empty = Empty
```

In case the first list is `Empty`, and the latter is not, then we return the second list.

```
concatenation Empty (Element b bs) = Element b bs
```

in case the first element is a list, and the latter is not, then we can return the first list:

```
concatenation (Element a as) Empty = Element a as
```

finally in case both lists are non-empty, then the resulting list starts with the first element of the first list, followed by the concatenation of the tail of the first list, and the second list:

```
concatenation (Element a as) (Element b bs) = Element a (concatenation as (Element b bs))
```

this gives us the following code:

```
concatenation:: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty Empty = Empty
concatenation Empty (Element b bs) = Element b bs
concatenation (Element a as) Empty = Element a as
concatenation (Element a as) (Element b bs) = Element a (concatenation as (Element b bs))
```

We can shorten the implementation with *as patterns*:

```
concatenation:: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty Empty = Empty
concatenation Empty bl@(Element b bs) = bl
concatenation al@(Element a as) Empty = al
concatenation (Element a as) bl@(Element b bs) = Element a (concatenation as bl)
```

But this is rather verbose, furthermore it performs pattern matching on both lists, which can be expensive: if for example the second list requires expensive computations first, and the first list is long enough (or even infinite), then we will never be interested in the second list anyway.

We thus can look if we can compact the number of clauses. The first two lines can be grouped together, from:

```
concatenation Empty Empty = Empty
concatenation Empty (Element b bs) = Element b bs
```

to:

```
concatenation Empty bl = bl
```

since regardless of the value of the second list, we return that anyway. It also saves us potentially an evaluation, which can result in more effecient code.

Can we do a similar thing with the last two lines?

```
concatenation (Element a as) Empty = Element a as
concatenation (Element a as) bl@(Element b bs) = Element a (concatenation as bl)
```

both have as a result an `Element` constructor, and `a` as the first element. Since the concatenation of `as` and `Empty` is eventually `concatenation as Empty = as`, we thus can perform a recursive call in the former case as well, and use:

```
concatenation (Element a as) bl = Element a (concatenation as bl)
```

and this results into:

```
concatenation :: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty bl = bl
concatenation (Element a as) bl = Element a (concatenation as bl)
```

we can omit the second parameter here with:

```
concatenation :: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty = id
concatenation (Element a as) = Element a . concatenation as
```

Note that the last reduction is not per se more efficient: this can result in constructing an entire copy of a (potentially large) list into memory, and a lot of computations if the second list turns out to be empty. If on the other hand computing the second list would result in getting stuck in an infinite loop or an expensive computation, and we are not interested in that part, we can potentially save a lot of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the standard recursion:

```
concatenation:: MyList a -> MyList a -> MyList a
concatenation Empty l = l
concatenation (Element e l1) l2 = Element e (concatenation l1 l2)
```

Why does it stop? The second rule with take every element of the first list, one by one, and nest it before the concatenation of `Empty` and the second list, that is the second list itself (first rule).

```
  concatenation Element 1 (... Element n (Empty)) l2
= Element 1 (concatenation Element 2 (... Element n (Empty))) l2 -- second rule
= ...
= Element 1 (Element 2 (... Element n (concatenation Empty l2))) -- second rule
= Element 1 (Element 2 (... Element n (l2))) -- first rule
```